# Prevent background layout from stretching

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make container size stretch to size of its items. But browser always stretches containers background width to 100%. Is there a way to prevent layout from stretch?

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mn73rc8z/)

```css
.content {
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.item {
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #BFC5C7;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">one</div>
  <div class="item">two</div>
  <div class="item">three</div>
  <div class="item">four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control the background 'width'.  The only thing you could do here would be to set a `width` or a `max-width` onto your `content` div, e.g.

```
.content{
  max-width:290px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

The other alternative, if you don't want to set a width on this element would be to give it a background image with the maximum width/height you expect your background to be and set it to `no-repeat`, e.g.

```
.content{
  margin-left: 50px;
  background:url(mySizedImage.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```